# best encryption algorithm for encrypting a string

Tags: aes, passwords, cryptocurrency

I am making a password manager , I am new to cryptography, so , can someone tell me if this can be a good solution?

1- the user inputs the email/password
2- all the payload gets encrypted with aes@256bit and saved on a public blockchain

It should work right?
and one more thing: as you know storing data on the blockchain is expensive , so , is AES a good algorithm for space optimization ?

Comment: Why is your password manager linked to a blockchain? Is this a learning exercise, a personal tool, or something you intend to share? I would recommend doing something like [KeePass](https://keepass.info/)/[KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/). Alternatively, you could do a command-line program like [pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/), except please don't use GPG.

Comment: @samuel-lucas6 it's just a learning exercise
I will deploy it on the bitcoin blockchain, with 1000s of nodes (better than bitwarden, right?)

Comment: There are anyways risks when developing software even if the cryptography is perfect. What if an attacker manages to send our a malicious update to your AES library? Then you might be strong badly encrypted passwords on the Blockchain for everyone to see. If this is not on the Blockchain, at least the damage is somewhat contained to whatever file synchronization system you're using.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you'd use the email for in the above scheme, but sure, that can be done. To transform a password into a key you'd need a password-based key derivation scheme (PBKDF). You could use the email as additional input, e.g. by using it as a salt or part of a salt.

Furthermore, you would need a mode of operation for AES. AES is a block cipher so itself simply takes a 16 byte plaintext as input and then produces a 16 byte ciphertext. A mode of operation can be used to encrypt multiple, longer messages. The result will however be at least as large as the password store: AES does not compress data in any way, and usually you'd need to store an IV and possibly an authentication tag.

Yes, you can store ciphertext in a public location. Storing it on a blockchain seems wasteful though. Generally, it seems more logical to store it in the cloud and keep local copies (and KeePass apps generally support Google and Dropbox, for instance).